# Media query for mobile applying to desktop

Tags: css

I'm not sure why my media query is working for sizes larger than specified. For example, an image with class `portrait` is showing up on my laptop as 250px rather than the 400px expected.

My media query is structured as follows and is at the end of my CSS.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.portrait {
    height: 250px;
  }
}
```

Full code: [Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/UtR760z2W0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extra closing brace in your `.about-text` style in the media query.

```
.about-text {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 1.4em;
  /* Removes margin added in main CSS */
  margin-bottom: 0;
  } <--
}
```

Simply remove that and it will work as expected.